# После обновления страницы пропадает содержимое виджета

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Установлен *Wordpress 4.6.1.*

Добавляю в виджет блок текст, сохраняю, а после обновления страницы все пропадает.

Сам виджет:

```
function true_register_wp_sidebars() {
   /* В боковой колонке - первый сайдбар */
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id' => 'сopyright', // уникальный id
            'name' => 'Копирайтинг', // название сайдбара
            'description' => 'Перетащите сюда виджеты, чтобы добавить их в сайдбар.', // описание
            'before_widget' => '', // по умолчанию виджеты выводятся <li>-списком
            'after_widget' => '',
            'before_title' => '', // по умолчанию заголовки виджетов в <h2>
            'after_title' => ''
        )
    );

    /* В подвале - второй сайдбар */
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id' => 'true_foot',
            'name' => 'Футер',
            'description' => 'Перетащите сюда виджеты, чтобы добавить их в футер.',
            'before_widget' => '',
            'after_widget' => '',
            'before_title' => '',
            'after_title' => ''
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'true_register_wp_sidebars' );
```